# How do I get rid off the following error?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am getting the following error when I am comparing two different images. But, if I compare an image with itself, the code works perfectly fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al1Yl.png)

CODE:

```
a = imresize(imread('02.03.bmp'),300/300);
b = imresize(imread('02.04.bmp'),300/300);
% basmati, book, box, scene
detector = cv.FeatureDetector('BRISK');
extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('BRISK');
tic
keypoints1 = detector.detect(a);
descriptors1 = extractor.compute(a, keypoints1);
keypoints2 = detector.detect(b);
descriptors2 = extractor.compute(b, keypoints2);
toc
index_pairs = matchFeatures(descriptors1,descriptors2);
matchpoints1 = [];
matchpoints2 = [];
for i = index_pairs(:,1)'
    matchpoints1 = [matchpoints1 keypoints1(i).pt'];
end
for i = index_pairs(:,2)'
    matchpoints2 = [matchpoints2 keypoints2(i).pt'];
end
figure;
subplot(121);
imshow(a);
hold on; scatter(matchpoints1(1,:),matchpoints1(2,:),'yo','LineWidth',.5);
subplot(122);
imshow(b);
hold on; scatter(matchpoints2(1,:),matchpoints2(2,:),'yo','LineWidth',.5);
```

ERROR:

> > feature_extraction
> >     Elapsed time is 0.290193 seconds.
> >     feature_extraction
> >     Elapsed time is 0.307123 seconds.
> >     Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in feature_extraction (line 31)
hold on; scatter(matchpoints1(1,:),matchpoints1(2,:),'yo','LineWidth',.5);

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of `matchpoints1`
It seems that size(matchpoints1,1)<2